# Error: Language is not supported and Error: The selected voice was not found

Tags: react-native, text-to-speech

i am working on react-native text to speech feature with react-native-tts, when i keep language default english it is able to translate but when change language english to hindi.it is showing above error.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
import Tts from 'react-native-tts'
 
Tts.setDefaultLanguage('hi-IN')
//Tts.setDefaultVoice('com.apple.ttsbundle.Lekha-compact')
 
const Home = () => (
 <Button
   title="Speak!"
   onPress={() => Tts.speak('वहां कोई है?')}
 />
)
 
export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different factors at play here that contribute to the issue at hand. Initially, it may seem as though the package itself is at fault for the problem at hand. However, upon closer examination, it becomes clear that the issue actually lies in the fact that Google does not support Arabic by default in Android devices. This lack of support means that the library in question is unable to find the package that it needs to function properly.

Fortunately, there are ways to work around this problem. One potential solution is to make use of the Google Text to Speech API. This powerful tool is capable of converting text into spoken words, which can be extremely useful in a variety of contexts. For more information on how to implement this solution, be sure to check out the article located at https://www.netguru.com/codestories/react-native-text-to-speech. By following the steps outlined in this resource, you can ensure that your application is able to handle Arabic text properly and provide a seamless user experience for all users, regardless of their language preferences.